# Problems swapping play and pause button

Tags: javascript, html, css

The buttons are displaying fine. When I click the 'play' button it runs the video but it doesn't hide 'play' and show 'pause'. When I click the 'pause' button, it hides 'pause' but not 'play'. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```js
const btnPlay = document.getElementById("btnPlay");
const btnPause = document.getElementById("btnPause");
btnPlay.addEventListener("click", vidPlay);
btnPause.addEventListener("click", vidPause);

function vidPlay() {
  btnPlay.classList.add("hidden");
  btnPause.classList.remove("hidden");
}

function vidPause() {
  btnPlay.classList.remove("hidden");
  btnPause.classList.add("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnPlay">Play</button>
<button id="btnPause" class="hidden">Pause</button>
```

Comment: I just made your code runnable, it seems good and does not have any errors

Comment: I think there is no any errors. It’s running and working without issues when I run the code.

Comment: If there is a problem, this snippet doesn't demonstrate it. When running the snippet, the button changes from play to pause and back again just fine. Was the snippet also supposed to display a video? because there is no code in here relating to displaying or playing a video.

Comment: I figured out the problem and it was a silly one... in my CSS I had `#btnPlay { display: block }` and forgot to remove it.